# Need SQL Query to coallate data from two tables in a desired format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table say clientDetails of 2 columns with `ClientID` and their associated `BranchCode` in separate columns.
I need a table with  distinct branches from this table in a column & all the clientids associated with this branch in another column with ',' seperated.
e.g.>
Table1:

```
Branch | ClientIDs

B001   | CLI001

B001   | CLI002

B001   | CLI003
```

**Result needed:**

```
Branch | ClientIDs

B001   | CLI001,CLI002,CLI003
```

What could be the best optimized way to get this data as record count is quite large.
 I need these columns to bind 2 comboboxes of a win form.

regards,
Ashish

Comment: Do you want an SQL-Server answer or a MYSQL answer?

Comment: I want SQL SERVER Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN SQL Server 2008,,

```
SELECT BRANCH, 
       Stuff((SELECT ',' + CLIENTIDS 
              FROM   CLIENTDETAILS a 
              WHERE  a.BRANCH = t.BRANCH 
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS ClientId 
FROM   CLIENTDETAILS t 
GROUP  BY BRANCH
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/532e4/2)

Comment: Is this a good option (i mean to say optimized one) to implement? can we use COALESCE to prepare string?

Comment: @AshishJaiswal  Yeah you can use Coalesce definately.That's the only way for your desired result which i know and seen yet so i think it's optimized one

Comment: Amit Can you pleae help me with the same?? i am new to SQL usage

Comment: @AshishJaiswal sorry i didnt get u?

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [Group_concat](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

```
SELECT BRANCH, 
       Group_concat(clientids) 
FROM   TABLE 
GROUP  BY BRANCH;
```

***[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b6e0/1)***

Comment: Sorry, I am using SQL SERVER2008

Comment: great. Why did you tagged mysql then?